# How to get product category id on product detail page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, product-view

I am trying to get product categories on product detail page.

I tried using

```
 $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

But it is not working for me.

Also i tried

```
  $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
  foreach($categories as $category)
  { 
     var_dump($category->getName());
  }
```

This code show me NULL value.

Can you guys help me with this? I am searching for solution from past 2 days. Now its a headache for me.

Thanks in advance.

/************* Edit**********/

I also tried by creating module block. But its not working for me:

Here is my code:

```
  <?php
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */

            /**
             * Product description block
             *
             * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
             */
            namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

            use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
            use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;


            class ProductsCategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
            {

                protected $_registry;
             /**
                 * @var Product
                 */
                protected $_product;

                /**
                 * Product option
                 *
                 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option
                 */
                protected $_option;

                /**
                 * Core registry
                 *
                 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
                 */
                protected $_registry = null;

                /**
                 * Catalog product
                 *
                 * @var Product
                 */
                protected $_catalogProduct;

                /**
                 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
                 */
                protected $_jsonEncoder;

                /**
                 * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
                 */
                protected $pricingHelper;

                /**
                 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
                 */
                protected $_catalogData;

                /**
                 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
                 * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper
                 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData
                 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
                 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option
                 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
                 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils
                 * @param array $data
                 */
                public function __construct(
                    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
                    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option,
                    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
                    array $data = []
                ) {
                    echo "coming in coonstructor";
                    $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
                    $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
                    $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
                    $this->_registry = $registry;
                    $this->_option = $option;
                    $this->arrayUtils = $arrayUtils;
                    parent::__construct($context, $data);
                }


                public function getCurrentCategory()
                {
                    return "fhdsfgdsf";
                }

            }
```

My phtml file:

```
     <?php //if ($currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory()): 
     $currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();
     ?>
    <div>
        <span><?php echo "testing";
        echo $currentCategory; ?></span>
    </div>
```

Called phtml via xml:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.category.name" template="product/view/productscategory.phtml" >
        </block></referenceContainer>
```

Comment: you can try with https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/category-ids-from-product-magento-2/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please use below code :

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getName();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. It works.. Can you tell me if i want to get name of category then what should i use?

Comment: please check my answer just edited.

Comment: So we can get the name and thats cool.. but how would i get enough info to build a real product list? (img, description, price, colors, etc...)

Comment: @JamesHarrington  like this, echo $cat->getDescription();  echo $cat->getImageUrl(); ...   try using a var_dump on $cat    like thos var_dump($cat)      then you can see every attribute it has

Comment: use dependency injection rather than object manager

Comment: how to check the condition if product not assigned to any category

Comment: @user46386  It gives you all the categories this product may belong but it doesn't give the current on the user came from like in the breadcrumbs. how can we get the current one ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

Create a custom module like below code.

create a module block file to get current category name.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block;
class Blockname extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

}
?>
```

create a phtml file with below code

```
<?php if ($currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory()): ?>
    <div class="detail-category-name">
        <?php echo $currentCategory->getName(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

call above phtml file via xml file.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Blockname" name="product.category.name" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/yourfilename.phtml" >
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

And finally you can see category name just above product name on product detail page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i already tried this code. I edited my answer with the code which i tried. I created custom module with name ProductsCategory.php and phtml file with name productscategory.phtml.