# How to get current category name in catalog view page(catalog_category_view.xml)?

Tags: magento2, php, category, catalog, phtml

I have a view model with a method for returning the category names from the current_product (Works in product view page). However it returns null when being used in the catalog view page (catalog_category_view.xml).

ViewModel:

```
namespace TheCompany\Theapp\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Gets current products Categories
 */
class CategoryLogic extends Template implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Category $categoryModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryModel = $categoryModel;
    }
    
    /**
     * Gets current products Categories
     *
     * @return Category[]
     */
    public function getProductCatagory()
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
        $arr =[];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cat = $this->categoryModel->load($category);
            $arr[] = $cat->getName();
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
?>
```

Phtml:

```
$viewModel = $block->getData('categoryLogic');
$categories = $viewModel->getCurrentProduct();
var_dump($categories);
```

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144117/how-to-get-product-category-id-on-product-detail-page-magento-2

Comment: maybe you need it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891841/how-to-get-current-category-in-magento2 @Justin Collins